# Converting a Pango Font Description to a string in Vala

Tags: string, vala, pango

I am trying to convert a Pango Font Description returned from a Font Chooser Dialog in GTK 3 to a string, however the C function:
     `pango_font_description_to_string()`
Does not work, as it is a different language. I have scoured the web in search of an answer, however it has been fruitless. Does anyone have any idea of how to convert a Pango font description to a String?

Comment: What do you mean by "different language"? What happens if you use .to_string() ?

Comment: What I meant was that C and Vala are different, so the function did not work. .to_string() did, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, but would you happen to know how to convert from string to Font Description?

Comment: You do know how Vala name mangling works, right? whenever there is a C function a la "some_object_function()", in Vala, it becomes SomeObject.function(). That's why I was able to find your function even though I never used Pango.

Comment: I only started to learn vala yesterday, so thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Are you working your way through the official Gnome tutorial as well as some easy GTK samples?

Comment: Yep, and I looked at one that had to do with Opening a file and making something to view it, and thought about making it so it can change the font, and then to store the font in GSettings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=pango/Pango.FontDescription) should have everything you need to know.

For getting the string representation, it is `my_description.to_string()`, for the reverse (description from string), it should be

```
var my_description = FontDescription.from_string("Description");
```